# Android: SkImageDecoder:: Factory returned null When retrieving image from gallery

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, gallery

The other day I encountered this issue when I was trying to get an image from a gallery (or a action pick intent).

Turns out this problem is caused because for some reason the file is corrupted, so Android will treat its size as 0 which will cause said error in the log, and if you try to display the image it will turn out blank.

Check the post bellow to know how I solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This also works for images retrieved by other means, as long as you treat them as files or can get a hold of their size.

Just do this

```
        File photo = new File(path_to_your_file);
        //Even if the size is 0, the file itself isn't null, so you need to check for this as well
        if(photo!=null){
            Double size = (double) photo.length();
            //transform the size from bytes to kb, for reasons.
            size = size/1024;
            //I can't recall a single instance when a file has a negative size, but lets just throw it in there to be sure.
            if(size<=0){
                Log.i("this image","ain't good");
            }else{
                 //do whatever you normally do with your file
            }
        }
```

Happy coding.